# calculating the hydrostatic pressure in a non-cuboid shaped container

Tags: fluid-statics

I want to calculate the hydrostatic pressure on the base at the following containers,but as you can see, the water are affecting the sides,especially in container 1, so does the formula $p$ $=$ $\rho$gh still applies in the these cases ?
     [image]

[image]

Comment: Almost a duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/281258/104696

Answer (score 0):

In equilibrium, the pressure in a fluid of a given density will be the same everywhere on a locus of gravitational equipotential. So the shape of the "container" does not matter, only the depth below the surface.

If it were not the case, then there would be non-vertical forces associated with the pressure gradients.