# On hydrostatic pressure and weight

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, weight

I'm doing some thought experiments about hydrostatic pressure and weighing setups on scales. This really confused me, so I really want to pick your brain about this and get some clarity.

Consider the following setup: Consider a classical balance scale. Next I have two 'containers' to pour water in. The first container is a cylinder with base area $A$ and height $h$. Now this cylinder has no base, so if you pour water into this cyclinder whilst holding the cylinder up, the water would simply fall through the cylinder. The second container is a cone-shaped and has the same base area as the cylinder, the same height, but it's radius decreases with the height (doesn't really matter how much).

Now put the first cylinder on the scale and pour water into the cylinder filling it. Next, attach a clamp firmly to the bottom of the cylinder (the clamp should be holding the weight of the cylinder but not the water as the water is simply hold in place by the cylinder but not supported by it as there is no base to rest on). If my understanding is correct, the only force that the scale can register is the weight of the water. In this case, the weight is $m\cdot g$ where $m$ is the mass of the water. Let $\rho$ denote the mass density of the water and $V$ the volume of the water, then $m=\rho\cdot V=\rho\cdot h\cdot A$ and thus the weight is $\rho\cdot g\cdot h \cdot A=P\cdot A$ where $P$ is the hydrostatic pressure of the fluid alone (I'm going to ignore atmospheric pressure, either because in this thought experiment, there is no atmosphere or I believe the pressure acting both on the water and scale should actually compensate each other). It should be noted that the only force acting on the scale is the pressure of the water (due to gravity).

Now repeat the previous experiment but with the second, cone-shaped, container. The only force acting on the scale again should by due to the pressure of the water. As is well known, hydrostatic pressure depends only on the depth of the water, not the shape of the container. Therefore, the scale should register the same 'weight' even though there is clearly less water in the second setup than the first.

My question is, is this reasoning correct? Is it really possible to balance different amounts of water on scales by only varying the shape of the container (which is not supported by the scale) holding the water in it's place?

I guess this must be correct. Imagine putting both setups on either sides of the scales. There is no difference between the scale acting a tunnel between both containers or literally connecting them to each other as communicating vessels, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://usuario.cicese.mx/~ovelasco/archivos/cursos/Wilson1995.pdf

Comment: @MarkoGulin: The second sentence says: "If the sides of the vessel slope generally inwards from bottom to top, than the force on the bottom is greater than the weight of the fluid contained." So if you can put such a setup on a scale and eliminate the 'weight' of the vessel itself (by supporting it with clamsp for example), the scale would actually register a weight more than due to the mass of the water itself. Correct? If that's correct, my only remaining question is whether such a setup can be achieved. Can you effectively balance 2L against 1L by playing with shapes and clamps?

Comment: You can never balance $2\ell$ against $1\ell$ on a correctly constructed and operated mass balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting idea although whether one could achieve the setup in practice is debatable.

[image]

The arrows labelled $w$ represent the forces exerted on the column of water by the containing vessel.

Perhaps what you have not realised is that when the container is cone shaped although the container has no effect on the scale it does have an effect on the water.
The container exerts forces $w$ on the water to hold the "orange" water up.
The scale exerts a force $F_2$ on the water equal to the weight of "blue" water $m'g$.
Thus the scale reading does charge between the two situations.

My answer to the post [Pressure at base of 3 different dam designs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281210/pressure-at-base-of-3-different-dam-designs/281258#281258) may be of interest?

---

Fortunately I have no thrown away my original diagram so I have now added the scenario (right-hand diagram) described by the OP.

The scale reading for the right-hand situation (magnitude $F_3$) is the same as the scale reading for the left-hand situation (magnitude $F_1$).
This is because although the column of liquid in the right-hand diagram does not weigh as much as the column of liquid in the left-hand diagram, ie $m''g<mg$, the container exerts forces, the $w$'s in the diagram, on the right-hand column of water which compensate for the "missing liquid.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'll look at the link as quickly as possible. One remark, I was actually considering a conical vessel inverted to yours (so wider at the bottom than top). 

Here I think it's somewhat obvious the container is supporting some weight of the water as it is 'above' the wall. With an inverted cone, even that dissappears which makes the setup less intuitive.

Comment: Okay, I've read your linked answer as well. I'm pretty sure I get that. Basically your answer here agrees with what I say. If you somehow make a setup where your scale only register the force due to pressure at the bottom, then of course setups with equal heights of water and the same base area will exert the same force (with the clamps I aim to eliminate the weight of the vessel).

For an inverted cylinder (wider at the bottom than top), the force applied is still the same, despite there being less water being supported by the scale as opposed to the cylindrical setup. Is that correct?

Comment: You can engineer a mass balance and clamped vessel to be balanced, but you cannot support different amounts of water and yet get balance. It is very clear that you did not get what it is you are reading.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent : With all due respect, your answers are not very enlightening and basically you're just telling me I don't understand anything. You might be right, but you're doing a horrible job at explaining. In Farcher's drawing above, the scale register the same force as the pressures at the bottoms are equal with equal areas. The sloping walls of the vessel on the right support the extra water and if the vessel is not being supported by the scale, this wouldn't register. Already here there is a setup with different amounts of water that can be balanced.

Comment: You can argue that this is not supporting 2L against 1L for example as the extra water is supported by the vessel itself. I agree with that. So now imagine the slope to be inward as you go up. The article you referred me to as well says: "If the sides of the vessel slope generally inwards from bottom to top, than the force on the bottom is greater than the weight of the fluid contained." Wouldn't that setup still balance as the only force acting on the scale is simply due to the pressure?

Comment: If not, your comment "You can never balance 2l against 1l on a correctly constructed and operated mass balance." doesn't explain anything to me. I clearly stated that something isn't clicking for me, you're just telling me over and over that I'm not getting it. Likely I'm not, but saying "I think you are in very serious misunderstanding of how everything here works" isn't teaching me anything at all.

Comment: Basically everybody on this page is trying to explain to you that you are seeing it wrongly, and if you keep insisting that "the only force acting on the scale is simply due to the pressure" then nobody can help you. You clamped the glass vessel onto the balance. Whatever downward force that the glass vessel is pushing onto the water to make the pressure correct, is going to be matched by an upward force on the glass vessel on the clamp, and thus the balance. How many times must we tell you that the glass vessel and clamps are doing something? It is not for lack of our trying to tell you.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent: Aha, I think we found a misunderstanding. You say "You clamped the glass vessel onto the balance." Did I? That was not my intention. The vessel should be clamped to something totally independent of the balance.

Comment: I have added a little more to my answer.

Comment: @Farcher: Thank you very much. It's a pretty useless experiment and potentially impossible to setup. In essence all this setup somewhat explains is the fact that water levels in communicating vessel are the same. In the last picture, naively, you'd say the scale is the only thing holding te water up (and it is), but it experiences way more force than just the weight of the water, to me, that's the interesting setup and is not intuitive. The explanation is easy though, the hydrostatic paradox isn't difficult, just suprising.

Comment: "The vessel should be clamped to something totally independent of the balance." That is precisely the case I was covering earlier: if it is clamped independent of the balance, then it must leak. There is no such thing as a flask clamped to something other than the balance and yet able to prevent leakages. I covered all these scenarios when I first wrote these things down.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent : A counterweight on the other side of the balance should be able to that. Said counterweight potentially must weigh more than the force applied by the water, but probably would still be sufficient to demonstrate that the force applied by the water can be way more or way less than the weight of the water alone. Last time I mentioned counterweights, I'm pretty sure you said the incredible helpful "very serious misunderstanding of how everything here works and not yet able to begin tackling this problem.". Hmm.

Comment: That is definitely a very serious misunderstanding. Let us assume that you have a counterweight so heavy that you can get the water to not leak. Then the weight of the water will be negligible compared to it. You will not be able to detect/demonstrate anything. Especially since the water is lifting the glass off the balance, there is no scheme you can do to get this to work. You can keep imagining weird scenarios, but then you do not get to claim to be learning any physics. You are already using the mass balance for comparing mass of water on two sides. There is no leeway for counterweights.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent :  Two things. First, let's not put both setups on either sides of the balance but do them seperately and just use normal weights on the other side. Both setups on both sides would be impossible as the clamps would simply be in the way (admittingly, whenever I say balance 2L against 1L, I'm thinking about the forces, not the actual setup which is perhaps impossible). 

Secondly, why would the weight of the water be negligible compared to the force needed te prevent leaking? What forces are at play there and how do you determine the magnitudes?

Comment: That is vagueness on your part. You should have asked that in the initial question statement, so that people will know that you meant a mass balance and not a spring balance, etc. If you have worked with tubes and flat surfaces, trying to prevent leakages, you would have known that, for a given water pressure, the pressure between cover and wall needed to prevent the leakage is very much bigger than the water pressure. This is partly because the relevant forces are perpendicular, counting on something similar to friction to work.

Comment: I can actually rather easily think of a way for the clamps to work just fine with mass balancing both setups on two sides. The problem is that if you add counterweights, then the precision of the mass balancing will need to be so absurdly high, that this will make Cavendish's experiment trivial to do, not to mention that adding counterweights on one side will negate the balancing on the other side. The fact of the matter is that there is no scheme in which this will work—it is vastly easier to do experiments demonstrating equal pressures holding up a lot more water, etc.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent : I'm sorry for the vagueness, that surely lead to the annoying misunderstanding on both sides. I clearly have never worked with tubes and flat surfaces, nor will I do so in the near future (thank god everyone). You say "the pressure between cover and wall needed to prevent the leakage is very much bigger than the water pressure." What exactly do you mean by cover in this case? What are the relevant forces at play in such situations? Do you have a link to relevant material? I'm not immediately seeing why forces needed to prevent leakage must be great.

Comment: In my mind, the vessel is a rigid unmoveable object able to resist any forces at play and the balance simply needs a large enough counterweight to prevent leakage. I have no idea how great that counterweight must be. I do see that water pressure (which works in all directions) would try to squeeze the water between the vessel and scale and here extra friction would be nice. I fail to see how to quantify those things though. Also, wouldn't it be easier to prevent leakage with fluids that have a higher viscosity? Or is that a dumb thing to say?

Answer (score 1):

> As is well known, hydrostatic pressure depends only on the depth of the water, not the shape of the container.

This is correct, but for a reason that you do not yet know.

> Therefore, the scale should register the same 'weight' even though there is clearly less water in the second setup than the first.

This is very wrong. The scale will register the weight of water and the flask holding them.

> Now this cylinder has no base, so if you pour water into this cyclinder whilst holding the cylinder up, the water would simply fall through the cylinder.

This is a very big issue. To make sure that there would be no leakages, the bottom must be something like rubber, and firmly pressed against the weighing scale, to provide enough traction to resist the water's pressure attempting to leak through the sides. It can be done, but the scale weighing will be difficult to do.

---

Where you actually went wrong, is that you assumed that the walls of the container do nothing. Instead, the water presses against the walls at the pressure for each height, and if the walls are slanted, then there will be a vertical component of pressing, either upwards or downwards, depending upon how the slanting is. In your case, it is downwards, i.e. the walls increase the pressure of the water just to agree with the height distribution, and in so doing, is being lifted off the scale by the water, increasing the likelihood of leakage. Similarly, a conical flask that is slanted the other way, will be lifting the water, and thereby be pressed downwards onto the scale by the water.

This is how the scale will always measure the weight of the water and the flask (and the excess securing force to prevent leakage), regardless of the shape of the walls.

Comment: You write: "The scale will register the weight of water and the flask holding them." In this experiment, the bottomless flask is being supported by a clamp near the bottom of the flask. Does the scale still register the flask in that case?

I'm well aware that balancing water without leakage is extremely difficult. The practical difficulties is not what concerns me here. 

I'm also aware the reaction force of the water pushing on the walls is what makes the hydrostatic paradox work.

Comment: My question really is, if you do this setup where the container is not supported by the scale but by clamps, is the resulting force on the scale in both setups the same? 

If the answer is yes, you can essentially balance 2L of water against 1L by varying the shape of the water,  the instrument used to force the water in different shapes must be supported by something other than the scale to make it work.

Also, thank you in advance for taking time to answer my questions! I do appreciate that.

Comment: My answer pointed out why it is that you are wrong and it is definitely not possible to balance $2\ell$ of water against $1\ell$, with reasoning why. Marko Gulin also deleted his original wrong answer and linked to a paper that talks around the correct answer I just gave. The scale must register the flask for this to work. If you lift the flask, then nothing can prevent the leakage.

Comment: @Mathematician42, Suppose some magic prevents water from leaking through the interface between the walls and the plate on the top of the scale. What you're still missing is that the clamp _cannot_ support the weight of a conical vessel that opens upward without also supporting some of the weight of the water. And, if the area of the opening where it touches the scale approaches zero, then the fraction of the water supported by the clamp approaches 100%. Water pressure is _normal_ to the surface of its container, and a vector normal to the surface of the cone has a _downward_ component

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent: Couldn't a counterweight on the other side of the balance counter the force applied by the water (and prevent leakage)?

Comment: @SolomonSlow: You say: "the clamp cannot support the weight of a conical vessel that opens upward without also supporting some of the weight of the water." I'm considering a conical vessel that closes upward, not opens upward. The bottom areas of both the conical vessel and cylindrical vessel are the same. 

If the vessel were conically opening upwards, your argument suggest that only the column of water above the area $A$ would apply force to the balance (which I do not dispute).

As for the magic, a counterweight on the balance could prevent leakage.

Comment: What do you even mean by a counterweight? If you are thinking of a mass balance as opposed to a spring balance, I think you are in very serious misunderstanding of how everything here works and not yet able to begin tackling this problem.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent: Yes, I'm thinking of a mass balance (where you possible add more weight on the side to prevent leakage and so on. 

You wrote: "the walls increase the pressure of the water just to agree with the height distribution, and in so doing, is being lifted off the scale by the water, increasing the likelihood of leakage." I really think you're missing that I wrote the vessels are being fixed in place by a clamp in the bottom (or really just part of a rigid structure not being supported by the weight.

Comment: My goal was simply to verify whether the force being applied over the entire bottom area $A$ can be more than the weight of the water. The second sentence in the article linked by Marko Gulin literally says that. Next, I want to somehow put such a construction on a scale where the bottom is removed and the vessel fixed by some other means. If I understand the forces at play, the only force the scale can register in such a setup is the pressure at the bottom. Is that correct?

Comment: That is simply not correct. Again, the glass necessarily will also exert a force, and this force can be upwards. If you started with both vessels anchored and water-tight and mass balanced, then under no circumstance will you obtain balance without equal masses of water on both sides, regardless of the height difference, i.e. the pressure difference, of the two sides. The clamp will just lift the balance to hold down the conical vessel if necessary.